# ggmap mapdist() not working after running devtools::install_github('dkahle/ggmap')

Tags: r, ggmap, devtools

I wonder if someone can help,

I ran`devtools::install_github('dkahle/ggmap')`  when trying to fix the issue of ggmap mapdist function repeating calculation for certain O-D pairs.

before running this the code `mapdist('Manchester Deaf Institute', 'Birmingham O2 Academy 1', mode = 'driving')` would return a result, however now after running `devtools::install_github('dkahle/ggmap')` 
I just get the following error `Error in`*tmp*`[[c(1, 1)]] : subscript out of bounds`

I am no where near the API limit for the day, and as this was working perfectly beforehand I am unsure why this is not working.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution but the only was I have been able to get past this is to uninstall and reinstall R.